# How to return errors from each node of a parallel process

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to use the `parallel` package (in fact, I'd like the solution to this problem to be general so I can use any parallelisation package) to run a given function and return any errors from any of the nodes that return one. Let's take a simple example.

```
parallel::parLapply(
  cl = parallel::makeCluster(2),
  list(1, 2),
  fun = function(x) {
    print(x)
    stop('test')
  }
)
```

So in this case my function prints its given value and then returns an error. If I run this code, I receive the following error

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: test
```

So I tried wrapping the code in a `tryCatch`

```
tryCatch(
  parallel::parLapply(
    cl = parallel::makeCluster(2),
    list(1, 2),
    fun = function(x) {
      print(x)
      stop('test')
    }
  ),
  error = function(e) e
)
```

Which gives the error

```
<simpleError in checkForRemoteErrors(val): 2 nodes produced errors; first error: test>
```

I also tried wrapping the function itself in a `tryCatch` to no avail.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  print(x)
  stop('test')
}

parallel::parLapply(
  cl = parallel::makeCluster(2),
  list(1, 2),
  fun = tryCatch(fun, error = function(e) e)
)
```

this gives the error

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: test
```

I know that this will work if I include the `tryCatch` within the actual function, for example

```
parallel::parLapply(
  cl = parallel::makeCluster(2),
  list(1, 2),
  fun = function(x) {
    print(x)
    tryCatch(stop('test'), error = function(e) e)
  }
)
```

this returns

```
[[1]]
<simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): test>

[[2]]
<simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): test>
```

But I want to be able to pass any random function to the `parLapply` and so I may not be able to add a `tryCatch`, nor do I want to add one just for the purposes of a parallel process - I'd rather add something once in the parallelisation itself.

Comment: Not familiar with R-internalities, yet - would you accept a clean separation of concerns - not messing a "return"-values-signature(s) yet get any of the errors reported via "other"-channel ( not restricted to { stdout | stderr } redirections )? That would yield a solution as a general framework for 1-main:N-processes or M-agents:N-processes communication scheme, which meets your requirement, including any indeed distributed-computing implementations thereof, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

So a solution to this is to wrap the actual function call in a `tryCatch` but you must ensure that the function is available in each cluster. You can do this by exporting it using `clusterExport` if it is not available from a package.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  print(x)
  stop('test')
}

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)

parallel::clusterExport(cl, "fun", env = environment())

parallel::parLapply(
  cl = cl,
  list(1, 2),
  fun = function(x) tryCatch(fun(x), error = function(e) e)
)
```

This will then return the errors as expected

```
[[1]]
<simpleError in fun(x): test>

[[2]]
<simpleError in fun(x): test>
```